# Creating dataframe from scratch with daily rows

Tags: python, pandas

What is the simplest code that can be used to create a basic dataframe with a single column (let's call it `date`), with daily rows between `dateA` and `dateB`?

This dataframe can later be used for multiple purposes.

I can think of many ways to create it, but all of them need multiple lines of code.  I wonder is there is a one liner, or an example of very simple code, for a task so simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2018-10-01','2019-09-01', freq='D')})
```